# run time error 1004 method open of object workbooks failed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, macros, templates, runtime-error

I have this issue on one single PC only, and the error relates to opening an Excel workbook based on a macro-enabled template (xltm).  Xltx files work fine.  (Macros are enabled on this troublesome PC).

Code is below, developed in Excel 2010, but functions correctly on separate PCs running 2010 & 2013 and various OS versions (Windows).

```
Dim xlTmp As Excel.Application
Set xlTmp = New Excel.Application
xlTmp.Visible = True
xlTmp.Workbooks.Add Template:="X:\TMS\4 Forms\45 PM\Bidding\45003 Costing Template.xltm"
```

As we have multiple xltm files, they must all reside on the server: multiple users need to access the templates.  I don't want to be changing code and risking access issues from other PCs.

I'm hopeful someone here can recommend a fix to the single PC that is causing the problem, please?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you open a new file based on that template via File > New > from existing? What happens if you add the folder to the trusted locations in Trust Center?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @teylyn
Adding folder (and subfolders) did not resolve.  Unable to find 'New...from existing in Excel 2013' (I can in 2010, but a google search didn't help either), I can only select online templates?)     I added the 'New...' buttton to the toolbar, but it just sends me to the 'New' backstage page again

Comment: ah, from existing was dropped in 2013. Use Windows Explorer to find the xltm, right-click and select New to create a new file from template. That will prompt the "do you trust this file" blurb and you can hit the button to trust. If that helps resolve the macro problem, let me know and I will post it as a proper answer.

Comment: Hi again, Right-click, New from xltm opened (successfully) an xls based on the template (i.e., what the macro should do).  No Trust Center option popped up.   So we can manually step through the process okay on this PC, but can't execute the VBA...?